# Momentum map and equivariance

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am reading an article in which I do not understand some equivariance property about the momentum map. Let $G$ be a Lie group acting on a manifold $Q$. The action is denoted $(g,q) \, \mapsto \, q \cdot g$. The standard notation $T_{id_{G}}G = \mathfrak{g}$ is used to represent the Lie algebra of $G$.

They define the momentum map by : $(q,p) \in Q \times T^*Q \, \mapsto \, m(q,p) \in \mathfrak{g}^*$ with :

$$ (m(q,p) \vert \xi) = (p \vert q \cdot \xi) , \, \xi \in \mathfrak{g} $$

Considering, $g \in G$, $q \in Q$, $p \in T^*Q$ and $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$, they write the following equalities :

\begin{eqnarray*}
(m(q \cdot g, p \cdot g) \vert \xi) & = & (p \cdot g \vert (q \cdot g) \cdot \xi) \\
 & = & (p \cdot g \vert q \cdot (g\xi)) \\
 & = & (p \vert (q \cdot (g\xi)) \cdot g^{-1}) \\
 & = & (p \vert q \cdot (g\xi)g^{-1}) 
\end{eqnarray*}

where $g\xi$ denotes the derivative of $h \, \mapsto \, gh$ in $h = id_{G}$ along the direction $\xi$ and $(g\xi)g^{-1}$ the derivative of $h \, \mapsto \, hg^{-1}$ in $h=g$ along the direction $g\xi$.

The first equality is just the definition of the momentum map. I do not understand the second equality. If I consider the left translation $L_{g} \, : G \, \rightarrow \, G ; h \, \mapsto \, gh$, I have $D_{id_{G}} L_{g} \, : \, \mathfrak{g} \, \rightarrow \, \mathfrak{g}$ the differential of $L_{g}$ at $id_{G}$. With their notations, is $g\xi$ equal to $D_{id_{G}} L_{g} \cdot \xi$ ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does (p|q⋅ξ) mean?

Comment: It is the value of the linear form $p$ at the point $q \cdot \xi$.

Comment: So what does  q⋅ξ mean? The group action is on G x T*Q, however ξ is in T*G.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm not sure I understand what they mean by $q \cdot \xi$. Differentiating the action $(g,q) \, \mapsto \, q \cdot g$, we can extend the action to the tangent bundle $TQ$. The action we get doing so is $(g,v) \, \mapsto \, v \cdot g$ where $v \in TQ$. By duality, we can define an action on the cotangent bundle $T^*Q$. If $p \in T^*Q$ and $v \in TQ*$, we set $(p \cdot g \vert v) = (p \vert v \cdot g^{-1})$. So, we have an action of $G$ on $T^*Q$. Differentiating at $g = id_{G}$ gives an action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $TQ$ which is $(\xi,v) \, \mapsto \, v \cdot \xi$

Comment: It makes me think that, in the definition of the momentum map, $q$ is in $TQ$ and $q \cdot \xi$ is the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $TQ$. Even though, it confuses me as, a few lines before this definition, $q$ was a point of $Q$.

Comment: $q \cdot \xi$ is bad notation, what they mean is the value at $q$ of the vector field on $Q$ generated by $\xi$ according to the infinitesimal action. The second equality you ask about just comes from the definition of this infinestimal action.

Comment: So, instead of $q \cdot \xi$, I shall write : $Q(q) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \big\vert_{t=0} exp(t\xi) \cdot q$ ?

Comment: Also comment that you can probably only make sense of the momentum map as a map $m : T^*Q \to \mathfrak{g}^*$ (defined by your formula above where $q$ is the basepoint of $p \in T^*Q$), since your pairing $(p|q\xi)$ only makes sense if $q$ is the basepoint of $p$.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, considering the right action of $G$ on the manifold $Q$ $(g,q) \, \mapsto \, q \cdot g$ and $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$, I can define the infinitesimal action $\xi_{Q}$ which is the fector field defined by : $\xi_{Q}(q) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \big\vert_{t=0} q \cdot \exp(t\xi), \, q \in Q$. Considering elements of the cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ are of the form $(q,p(q))$ with $q \in Q$ and $p(q) \in (T_{q}Q)^*$, I can define the momentum map $m \, : \, T^*Q \, \rightarrow \, \mathfrak{g}^*$ through : $(m(q,p(q)) \vert \xi) = (p(q) \vert \xi_{Q}(q))$.